# select into ... with (data_compression = ...)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is ther a way to 'select into' a table using/invoking data_compression for that table on SQL-Server (like there is on Sybase)?

Like

```
select 'hello' c1 
into #t1 
with (data_compression = page)
```

what gives an syntax error. Creating the table using options is the obvious way but implies to use 'insert'.

Comment: You can't use select into with compression, you can however rebuild the new table with compression after the insert with `ALTER TABLE TableName REBUILD PARTITION = ALL  
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)`.